# closed formula for a linear combinations of Euler's totient function

Tags: number-theory

‎Suppose $G$ is a finite group and ${\cal C}(G)$ denotes the set of all conjugacy classes of $G$‎. ‎The normal graph of $G$‎, ‎${\cal N}(G)$‎, ‎is a finite simple graph such that $V({\cal N}(G)) = {\cal C}(G)$‎. ‎Two conjugacy classes $A$ and $B$ in ${\cal C}(G)$ are adjacent if and only if there is a normal subgroup $N \unlhd G$ such that $A \cup B \leq N$‎.
For counting the number of edges of the normal graph of a finite group $G$, I have to find a formula for $\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)^{2}$. Is there any closed formula?

Comment: There probably is a closed formula. Note that your sum is multiplicative since the Euler totient function (and powers of it!) are multiplicative. Consider finding this sum for prime powers then use the multiplicative property of the sum. That may bring you to a form that you are looking for.